# If I have an Equipment equipped to something and it's enchanted by Ensoul Artifact, how is that handled?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Imagine I have an Equipment attached to something, e.g. a [Chariot of Victory](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Chariot%20of%20Victory) on a [Runeclaw Bear](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Runeclaw%20Bear). I then enchant that equipment with [Ensoul Artifact](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ensoul%20Artifact).

Would the Equipment card still grant its effects to the creature it was attached to? Additionally, would it still be able to attack? Or is it treated more like an enchanted creature?

Comment: Your question was a little hard to follow - I tried to edit it into something clear, but I'm not 100% sure if it asks everything you were trying to ask. Please edit further if not!

Comment: Are you asking whether the equipment will gain the effets of ensoul artifact, or if it will gain _its own_ effects?

Comment: @doppelgreener I'm asking for: will the equipment grant its effects to its "equiper" and also can still be tapped by it self to attack, as a creature can do.

Comment: @Zaibis Ok, thanks for clarifying. I've edited the question, please check it over and see if it captures what you're after.

Comment: @doppelgreener: Didn't the edit falsified that? (sorry if my english is jsut worse)

Comment: @Zaibis Oh. Are you asking if it can still be equipped to something, and give its effects to that thing, while also being a creature that can attack on its own?

Comment: @doppelgreener: exactly thats what I asked other wise I guess it would be a duplicate ^^

Comment: @Zaibis Ok, how is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An Equipment Creature can't be attached to anything, so there is no Equipped Creature to which to grant a boon. If a [Chariot of Victory](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Chariot%20of%20Victory) was animated using Ensoul Artifact, it would not grant First Strike, Trample and Haste to anything, much less itself.

---

> 301.5a The creature an Equipment is attached to is called the “equipped creature.” The Equipment is attached to, or “equips,” that creature.

It's impossible to use the Equip ability of Creature Equipment.

> 301.5c An Equipment that’s also a creature can’t equip a creature. [...]

If for some reason an Creature Equipment is attached to an object or player, it will cease to be when State-Based actions are performed.

> 704.5q If a creature is attached to an object or player, it becomes unattached and remains on the battlefield. Similarly, if a permanent that’s neither an Aura, an Equipment, nor a Fortification is attached to an object or player, it becomes unattached and remains on the battlefield.

Comment: Wouldn't 301.5c actually stop you from attaching a creature equipment to itself? The SBA handles the case where an attached equipment becomes a creature, but 301.5c prevents a creature equipment from becoming attached.

Comment: FYI the question has been edited to capture the asker's intentions. They were not trying to ask about whether the equipment would gain its own equip benefits.

Comment: @doppelgreener, np. Already covered by my answer

Comment: @ikegami: does this technically mean: I can technically pay the costs for equipping it, but after that it will instantly unequip and remain in a state it was before (as long the equiping process didn't changed anything in its state)?

Comment: @ikegami I'm pretty sure that "can't equip" in rule 301.5c refers to the definition of "equips" in rule 301.5a. It is not saying that you can't activate the equip ability.

Comment: @ikegami If you read the rest of rule 301.5c, the only meaning that makes sense is "attached". Read the last paragraph: "If a spell or ability would cause an Equipment to equip more than one creature, the Equipment’s controller chooses which creature it equips.". See rule 303.4d for the equivalent rule for auras, using analogous wording.

Comment: @Pablo, It can't mean "attached" (because it's possible for a creature to be attached until SBAs fix the situation), but maybe it means "become attached". (If so, that would mean you could activate a creature's Equip ability, but it wouldn't do anything on resolution.)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Ensoul Artifact on an equipment it will not gain the effects it grants to the equipped creature. This is because the equipment is not equipping itself (it can't equip anything as long as it is a creature). So a [Bonesplitter](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bonesplitter) enchanted with Ensoul Artifact will be a 5/5, not 7/5.

Comment: FYI the question has been edited to capture the asker's intentions. It is asking about something different to this.